# How to read the firebase database and put it in tableview cells issue

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, tableview

I am a swift beginner,and I want to get value from firebase database,but it always recived twice same dictionary structure,and can't put value in tableview cells when I unwrapping it crashed...

**here is my JSON format**

[image]

**Code work**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
//import FirebaseAuthUI
//import FirebaseGoogleAuthUI
//import FirebaseFacebookAuthUI

let device = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

class MainTableViewController: UITableViewController
{
    var dic:NSDictionary?

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //獲取當前登陸用戶
        FIRAuth.auth()?.addStateDidChangeListener(self.UserAlive(auth:user:))
        print("主畫面viewDidLoad")
    }

    func UserAlive(auth: FIRAuth, user: FIRUser?)
    {
        if user == nil
        {

            self.present((self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignIn"))!, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        else
        {
            csGolbal.g_User = user
            CheckData()
        }
    }

    func CheckData()
    {
        print("CHECKDATA")           
        let ref = device.child("USER").child(csGolbal.g_User!.email!.replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: "_"))

        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with:
            { (snapshot) in
                if snapshot.exists()
                {
                    csGolbal.g_key = ((snapshot.value as AnyObject).allKeys)!
                }
                ref.child(csGolbal.g_key![0] as! String).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with:
                    { (snapshot) in
                        // Get user value
                        self.dic = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                        print(self.dic)
                        //self.tableView.reloadData()
                })
        })

    }
```

and here is I don't get it how to put in

```
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows

        if let number = csGolbal.g_key?.count
        {
            return number
        }
        else
        {
            return 0
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MainTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MainTableViewCell

        //put in here
        // label.text and ImageView

        return cell
    }
```

please hlep me,and tell me where I am do wrong.

**@dahiya_boy  I try your function**

```
func getDataFromDB()
    {
        DispatchQueue.main.async( execute: {

            //let dbstrPath : String! = "Firebase Db path"
            let ref = device.child("USER").child(csGolbal.g_User!.email!.replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: "_"))

            ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                if !snapshot.exists()
                {
                    print("snapshot not exists")
                }
                else
                {

                    for item in snapshot.children
                    {
                        let number = item as! FIRDataSnapshot
                        var aDictLocal : [String : String] = number.value! as! [String : String]
                        aDictLocal.updateValue(number.key, forKey: "key")

                        print("value \(number.value!) And Key \(number.key)") // Here you got data
                    }
                }
                 self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
        })

    }
```

**and the result feedback twice**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you have stored Data in DB in random key so use below func

```
func getDataFromDB(){
        DispatchQueue.main.async( execute: {

            let dbstrPath : String! = "Firebase Db path)"

            dbRef.child(dbstrPath!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                if !snapshot.exists(){

                    print("snapshot not exists")

                }
                else{
                    self.arrEmail.removeAll() // Add this
                    for item in snapshot.children {
                        let number = item as! FIRDataSnapshot
                        var aDictLocal : [String : String] = number.value! as! [String : String]
                        aDictLocal.updateValue(number.key, forKey: "key")
                        self.arrEmail.append(aDictLocal) // add this
                        print("value \(number.value!) And Key \(number.key)") // Here you got data
                    }
                }
               // self.tblContacts.reloadData()
            })
        })

    }
```

> Edit

Create one global array like below in your VC

```
    var arrEmail = [[String : String]]() // Assuming your key and value all string
```

In the above code work add two lines (I edited and with comment **add this**)

```
self.arrEmail.removeAll()
```

and

```
self.arrEmail.append(aDictLocal) // Now in arrEmail you have all the values for every random key.
```

Comment: CheckData replaced by getDataFromDB()?

Comment: @benjamin Yeah! use this func

Comment: It's will query twice and feedback twice value...,and should I search this user's Email to know random key before observeSingleEvent data?

Comment: This is only way, You can not render random by email. Which value you getting twice??

Comment: add in your ques what u got.

Comment: I meaning it will have many random key in every user's Email,and how would I know each random keys,and according to each random keys to get this username,company's value and put it in tableview cells.